# Stop pre-selected (highlight) item in JQuery Mobile listview

Tags: html, css, listview, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an App for iOS and Android, I'm using **JQuery Mobile 1.4.3** + Phonegap Build. My navigation App is based on JQuery Mobile listviews. I have pages with links inside the listviews to go another pages.

The problem is that are pre-selected (**highlighted**) items when go from one page with listview to another with listview.

The pre-selected item is the 'n' number that you selected in the first one. For example: if in the first page you selected the third item, in the second page will be pre-selected (highligthed) the third item.

My listviews are normal, just like this:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><a href="paginas/asociaciones.html">Asociaciones / Misiones</a></li>
        <li><a href="paginas/hospitales.html">Hospitales</a></li>
        <li><a href="paginas/uniones.html">Uniones</a></li>
        <li><a href="paginas/universidades.html">Universidades</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a screen how it see when the second page is loaded. It's highlighted an item by default:

[image]

This bug it's shown only in mobile devices (iOS and Android); in mobile browsers and installed App.

I've not founded a solution for this JQuery Mobile bug. Any idea how fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging my App with Safari's web inspector I see that JQM applies automatically the `:hover` class to this kind of listviews.

**Solution:**
Like in the mobile environment the hover doesn't exist I modify my CSS class `.ui-listview .ui-btn:hover` of my JQM theme and changing the `background-color`. Like this:

```
.ui-listview .ui-btn:hover {
    background-color: transparent!important;
}
```